# How to keep jump starter fully charged

Tags: electrical

How can I connect a jump starter to my truck so the jump starter is always fully charged when I need to give someone a jump? The jump starter is a Matco PS2200JS, the truck is a 2011 Ranger 4L-V6. I want to include an isolator.

Comment: You could actually maintenance charge it from a low current switched source (cig lighter outlet for example). I'm sure it would not take more than 10 amp to maintain. Use a suitable fuse..  I see that model has a built in charger btw, does it plug right into AC or use a wall wart?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a heavy duty relay operated by the ignition switch - so the battery is connected to the alternator output when the engine is running and separated when it is off. There are many devices sold for this - check out caravanning supplies they use second or auxiliary batteries. Make sure you use a cable of sufficient thickness (capable of 60A or so.).